# Compile android project to apk without eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, obfuscation, apk

What I have done is I have taken the class-files from my eclipse project and run them trough an optimizer/obfuscator. So I now have optimized class-files that I want to get in the form of an apk so I can sign and publish it. However, I am lost on how to do this. I guess I cant just copy them into the bin-folder of my eclipse-project, because eclipse would just overwrite them with a new compilation when I try to export a signed apk. So how do I create an apk from these class-files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try to put them in bin/classes and then use "ant" command to build your application

```
cd /path/to/my/app
ant release
```

it will ask you every time for your private key to sign the app, it can be configured to auto-sign by editing "build.properties" file:

```
key.store=release.keystore
key.alias=release
key.store.password=my_key_password
key.alias.password=my_key_password
```

you can also investigate Android SDK, find the ANT build scripts it actually uses, and insert your custom obfuscator/optimizer call in middle of build process.

Comment: Thansk! But I just spent half a day trying to do this and failed. Guides I have found have presumed that I have a build.xml in my project directory, which I have not. I have tried to take a build.xml from a sdk sample, but have failed to convert it to work on my project :'( Any ideas?

Comment: run "android update project --path /path/to/your/project --target 3"

Comment: you can list targets with "android list target" cmd

Comment: i finally got it... some enviromental variable pointed towards an old SDK and screwed with "list target". :P thanks for the help

Comment: sry just realized that it did not work... ant compiles the java-files. I will have to have a look at the ant script tomorrow :(

Comment: solved it... removed the <target name="compile"-tag from the ant-file in the corresponding platform-folder, and also removed all dependencies on this tag, i.e. all depends="compile". Now it works! :D

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example:

```
android create project \
--target 1 \
--name MyAndroidApp \
--path ./MyAndroidAppProject \
--activity MyAndroidAppActivity \
--package com.example.myandroid
```