# how can I build an android project without eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build.xml

I have an android application created and built in eclipse, it's made of 2 projects containing several packages. 
I need to build it out of eclipse in order to get the build.xml file.
I found this:

```
  android create project \
--package com.example.helloandroid \
--activity HelloAndroid \
--target 2 \
--path <path-to-your-project>/HelloAndroid
```

problem is, I have many packages and I'm not sure how to build it.
do I need to specify all of them? how?

Comment: my solution was to build my project in eclipse, using the option of export -> ant buildfile which generated the build.xml file I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems similar to the solution you're looking for I assume:

[Compile android project to apk without eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988200/compile-android-project-to-apk-without-eclipse)