# Android - Build application without eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, build, aapt

I have one main application and an Android library project that it 
uses

I can compile and run the application fine in eclipse

when I try to build the same app using ant I am facing issues

I am not able to get the same result with aapt that eclipse does(in 
the background)

eclipse plugin seem to merge the resources together (layouts, icons, 
strings, etc) for both the main app and the library project. 
Anyone knows how to do this in command line in aapt

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

It has everything about building without Eclipse.

Comment: Thx but there's absolutely no information about how to build with Android library project.

Comment: it does it out of the box...use the command line to update the project build configuration (see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/android.html command: android update project), it will get the referenced library projects from the project.properties file

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your applicaiton without eclipse using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988300/1405983) way. Its a perfect idea. Also refer [this blog](http://blog.standalonecode.com/?p=269).