# Build Android Studio app via command line

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, command-line, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build an Android Studio app (the Gradle build system), but I want to do this via the command line.

Comment: For example ./gradlew assembleRelease, ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: If you have multiple build variants, then you should go ./gradlew assembleYourVariantRelease

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Android Studio automatically creates a [Gradle wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) in the root of your project, which is how it invokes Gradle. The wrapper is basically a script that calls through to the actual Gradle binary and allows you to keep Gradle up to date, which makes using version control easier. To run a Gradle command, you can simply use the `gradlew` script found in the root of your project (or `gradlew.bat` on Windows) followed by the name of the task you want to run. For instance, to build a debug version of your Android application, you can run `./gradlew assembleDebug` from the root of your repository. In a default project setup, the resulting apk can then be found in `app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`. On a *nix machine, you can also just run `find . -name '*.apk'` to find it, if it's not there.

Comment: It took me more than 2 hours to understand what's the proper way to run Gradle from the command line

Comment: I ran this from command line `c:\path_to_my_app\gradlew.bat ./gradlew assemblyDebug`, and it showed me **Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip**. And it's stuck there. What do I miss?

Comment: You can also install the app with `./gradlew installArm7Debug`.  Other tasks are easy to find from `./gradlew tasks`

Comment: I compiled the project and uploaded it to the Android device using `./gradlew assembleDebug` and `./gradlew installDebug` commands. In the AndroidStudio there is a console which monitors all Android device activities real-time (e.g. if the Android device crashes, the console prints the exception trace). How to get this monitoring facility on a terminal?

Comment: How to prevent the gradle from Downloading the ->  Downloading services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.xyz-all.zip . I noticed the gradle builds the android project fine but on the command line there is an issue of proxy setting. It can be resolved by putting the proxy settigns (but right now I dont have that priviledge) but I just want to bypass the downloading thing..How can I do that?

Comment: i am getting error when build from command line ./gradlew assebleDebug Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent

Comment: on windows `c:\path_to_my_app\gradlew.bat  assemblyDebug ` replace c with your drive and path_to_my_app with your subfolder(s) path...

Answer (score 33):

there are two build types to build your application using the Gradle build settings: one for debugging your application — debug — and one for building your final package for release — release mode.

### **Building in Debug Mode**

- First Navigate to Android studio project Root folder using CMD
  [image]
- run this command  **gradlew.bat assembleDebug**
- Output window look like this
  [image]

### **Build signed apk in Release Mode**

- Edit the build.gradle file to build your project in release mode:

  ```
   android {
   ...
   defaultConfig { ... }
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
           storePassword "password"
           keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
           keyPassword "password"
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           ...
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }}
  ```

[image]

- run this command **gradlew.bat assembleRelease**

Comment: Is there a way to auto launch app after build successfull ?

Comment: I can't find any way to auto launch app after build

Comment: @DhavalJivani launch it in an emulator you mean? If so that's just simple adb commands. You can even target a specific activity to launch.  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: @DhavalJivani what is best way to test android app in automation testing?. As for web we have selenium in python and node.

Comment: @HarshManvar
 Appium supports both Android and iOS platforms, making it a good choice if you need to automate tests for apps on multiple platforms.

Appium supports multiple programming languages, including Java, Python, JavaScript, Ruby, and C#. This flexibility allows you to choose a language that your team is comfortable with.

Answer (score 32):

Try this (OS X only):

`brew install homebrew/versions/gradle110`
`gradle build`

You can use `gradle tasks` to see all tasks available for the current project. No `Android Studio` is needed here.

Comment: Make sure you have homebrew installed to begin with!

Comment: "no Android Studio needed" - unless you need the Android SDK I guess. At any rate, the project I am trying to build does ask for it.

Answer (score 21):

#### 1. Install Gradle and the Android SDK

Either

- Install these however you see fit
- Run `./gradlew`, or `gradlew.bat` if on Windows

  - `chmod +x ./gradlew` may be necessary

From this point onwards, `gradle` refers to running Gradle whichever way you've chosen.
Substitute accordingly.

#### 2. Setup the Android SDK

- If you've manually installed the SDK

  - `export ANDROID_HOME=<install location>`
  - You may want to put that in your `~/.profile` if it's not done automatically
- Accept the licenses: `yes | sdkmanager --licenses`

  - `sdkmanager` can be found in `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`
  - `sdkmanager` may have to be run as root
- Try running `gradle`

  - If there are complaints about licenses or SDKs not being found, fix the
    directory permissions

    - `chown -R user:group $ANDROID_HOME`
    - If you're reckless and/or the only user: `chmod 777 -R $ANDROID_HOME`

#### 3. Building

- `gradle tasks` lists all tasks that can be run
- `:app:[appname]` is the prefix of all tasks, which you'll see in the Gradle
  logs when you're building

  - This can be excluded when running a task

**Some essential tasks**

- `gradle assemble`: build all variants of your app

  - Resulting .apks are in `app/[appname]/build/outputs/apk/[debug/release]`
- `gradle assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease`: build just the debug or release versions
- `gradle installDebug` or `installRelease` build and install to an attached device

  - Have [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) installed
  - Attach a device with USB debugging and USB file transfer enabled
  - Run `adb devices`, check that your device is listed and *device* is
    beside it

**Automatically build and install upon changes**

This avoids having to continuously run the same commands

```
gradle -t --continue installDebug
```

- `-t`: aka `--continuous`, automatically re-runs the task after a file is changed
- `--continue`: Continue after errors. Prevents stopping when errors occur

#### Run `gradle -h` for more help

Answer (score 9):

## You're likely here because you want to install it too!

#### Build

```
gradlew
```

(On Windows `gradlew.bat`)

#### Then Install

```
adb install -r exampleApp.apk
```

(The `-r` makes it replace the existing copy, add an `-s` if installing on an emulator)

#### Bonus

I set up an alias in my `~/.bash_profile`, to make it a 2char command.

```
alias bi="gradlew && adb install -r exampleApp.apk"
```

(Short for Build and Install)

Answer (score 7):

Cheatsheet for running Gradle from the command line for Android Studio projects on Linux:

```
cd <project-root>
./gradlew
./gradlew tasks
./gradlew --help
```

Should get you started..

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem and seems that there have been many changes by google.

I can tell you the steps for installing purely via command line from scratch.
I tested it on Ubuntu on 22 Feb 2021.

#### create sdk folder

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk
sudo mkdir -p $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

#### install openjdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

#### download android sdk

Go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
Then down to Command line tools only
Click on Linux link, accept the agreement and instead of downloading right click and copy link address

```
cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
sudo wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
sudo unzip commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
```

#### move folders

Rename the unpacked directory from cmdline-tools to tools,
and place it under $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools,
so now it should look like: $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools.
And inside it, you should have: NOTICE.txt  bin  lib  source.properties.

#### set path

```
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
```

This had no effect for me, hence the next step

#### browse to sdkmanager

```
cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
```

#### accept licenses

```
yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses
```

#### create build

Finally, run this inside your project

```
chmod 777 gradlew
sudo ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

This creates an APK named -debug.apk at //build/outputs/apk/debug
The file is already signed with the debug key and aligned with zipalign,
so you can immediately install it on a device.

#### FINAL STEPS

Here are the final steps. Make 2 .sh files with these contents. Use `chmod 777` before on both. No sudo required.

Download_APK_Code_NOSUDO4.sh

```
# Don't forget to do chmod 777 Download_APK_Code_NOSUDO2.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "camera-samples" ]; then
  echo "############################# Deleting older code base.      ######################################"
  rm -rf camera-samples
fi

echo "###########################     Download Source Code: Start ... #####################################"
git clone git://git.quicinc.com/camera-samples -b iot-concam-apk.lnx.1.1
echo "##########################      Download Source Code: Done . . . ####################################"
```

Build_App_NOSUDO4.sh

```
# Don't forget to do chmod 777 Build_App_NOSUDO2.sh
#!/bin/bash

currentDir=$(pwd)
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$(pwd)

# echo "############################################   Install JDK ...  ################################################"
# apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

if [ -e "commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip" ]; then
  echo "############################# Deleting older zip file.      ######################################"
  rm -rf commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
fi
echo "###########################################   Download Command Line Tools .. ###################################"
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
echo "###########################################   Download Command Line Tools Done .. ##############################"

if [ -d "cmdline-tools" ]; then
  echo "############################# Deleting older cmdline-tools.      ######################################"
  rm -rf cmdline-tools
fi
echo "###########################################   Unzip Command Line Tools Start .. #################################"
unzip commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
echo "###########################################   Unzip Command Line Tools Done .. #################################"


echo "###########################################   Creating Directory Structure .. #################################"
mv cmdline-tools tools
mkdir cmdline-tools
cp -r  tools cmdline-tools/
rm -rf tools/


PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
echo "##########################################   Updated Path : $PATH ###############################################"

cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin

echo "##########################################   Accept All Licenses .. #############################################"
yes | sdkmanager --licenses

cd $currentDir/camera-samples/Camera2Video
echo "sdk.dir = $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" > local.properties

echo "########################################     Building APK . . . #################################################"
chmod 777 gradlew
./gradlew assembleDebug
echo "#######################################      Building APK Done. . .  ############################################"

echo "##################################### APK generated here:  $currentDir/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk ###################################"
##########################################################
```

Run these commands.

```
chmod 777 Download_APK_Code_NOSUDO4.sh
chmod 777 Build_App_NOSUDO4.sh
./Download_APK_Code_NOSUDO4.sh
./Build_App_NOSUDO4.sh
```

#### REFERENCES

https://gist.github.com/guipmourao/3e7edc951b043f6de30ca15a5cc2be40

[Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)

["Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273412/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not)

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#sign_cmdline

///////////////////////////////////

### WINDOWS

Here are the steps for Windows via Powershell. Tested on 6th March 2021. You can start completely from scratch.

Prerequisites

1. Download git
2. Install JDK. I used jdk-8u281-windows-x64.exe

Make a file DownloadAndBuild.ps1 with these contents.

```
$location = Get-Location

if (Test-Path "$location\camera-samples") {
    Write-Host "########################### Deleting older code base: Start. ################################"
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path "$location\camera-samples"
    Write-Host "########################### Deleting older code base: Done. #################################"
}
Write-Host "########################## Download Source Code: Start. #####################################"
git clone https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/camera-samples -b iot-concam-apk.lnx.1.1
Write-Host "########################## Download Source Code: Done. ####################################"


if (Test-Path "$location\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip") {
    Write-Host "########################### Deleting older zip file: Start. ################################"
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path "$location\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip"
    Write-Host "########################### Deleting older zip file: Done. #################################"
}
Write-Host "########################## Download Command Line Tools: Start. #####################################"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip","commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip")
Write-Host "########################## Download Command Line Tools: End. #####################################"

if (Test-Path "$location\cmdline-tools") {
    Write-Host "########################### Deleting older folder: Start. ################################"
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path "$location\cmdline-tools"
    Write-Host "########################### Deleting older folder: Done. #################################"
}
Write-Host "########################## Extract Command Line Tools: Start. #####################################"
Expand-Archive "$location\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip" -DestinationPath "$location"
Write-Host "########################## Extract Command Line Tools: End. #####################################"



Write-Host "########################## Create Directory Structure: Start. #####################################"
Rename-Item -Path "$location\cmdline-tools" -newName "$location\tools"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$location\cmdline-tools"
Move-Item -Path "$location\tools" -Destination "$location\cmdline-tools"
Write-Host "########################## Create Directory Structure: End. #####################################"

Write-Host "########################## Accept Licenses: Start. #####################################"
Set-Location -Path $location/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
for($i=0;$i -lt 100;$i++) { $response += "y`n"}; $response | ./sdkmanager.bat --licenses
Write-Host "########################## Accept Licenses: End. #####################################"


Write-Host "########################## Build APK: Start. #####################################"
Set-Location -Path $location/camera-samples/Camera2Video
$Env:ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = $location
.\gradlew assembleDebug
Write-Host "########################## Build APK: End. #####################################"

Write-Host "##################################### APK generated here:  $location/camera-samples/Camera2Video/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk ###################################"
PAUSE
```

Right-click and run via Powershell.
This will download an Android project via git, install the SDK and build the Android App.

Edit as per your convenience.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28382761)

Comment: I have added the full answer here.

Answer (score 5):

**Build Android app by command line**

MacOS variant

```
./gradlew <moduleName>:assemble<build_variant>
//e.g
./gradlew <moduleName>:assembleDebug
```

*`./` means current directory

[[More info]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918303/4770877)

Answer (score 4):

For Mac use this command

```
  ./gradlew task-name
```

Answer (score 2):

**Only for MAC Users**

Extending [Vji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2838776/vji)'s answer.

Step by step procedure:

1. Open Terminal
2. Change your directory to your Project(cd PathOfYourProject)
3. Copy and paste this command and hit enter:

   ```
   chmod +x gradlew
   ```
4. As [Vji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2838776/vji) suggested:

   ```
   ./gradlew task-name
   ```

   DON'T FORGOT TO ADD .(DOT) BEFORE /gradlew

Answer (score 2):

[Official Documentation is here:](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline)

To build a debug APK, open a command line and navigate to the root of your project directory. To initiate a debug build, invoke the `assembleDebug` task:

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

This creates an APK named `module_name-debug.apk` in `project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/`.

Answer (score 0):

note, you can also do this within Android Studio by clicking the gradle window, and then the 'elephant' button. This will open a new window called "run anything" (can also be found by searching for that name in 'search everywhere') where you can manually type any gradle command you want in. Not "quite" command line, but often provides more of what I need than windows command line.

This allows you to give optional params to gradle tasks, etc.

Answer (score -1):

`enter code here`Create script file with  below gradle and adb command, Execute script file

```
./gradlew clean
```

./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew installDebug

adb shell am start -n applicationID/full path of launcher activity

Answer (score -2):

Adding value to all these answers,

many have asked the command for running App in AVD after build sucessful.

```
adb install -r {path-to-your-bild-folder}/{yourAppName}.apk
```