# How to remove Gradle Conflicts

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Total Method Count in my project is`155,323`. There are many libraries i am using. 
First i was using play services like this.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
```

I was getting `ClassDefNotFound` error in `GoogleVR:` related classes.

Then i removed the general library of `play-services`, and added the specific ones.  The error was gone. I was happy and surprised.

Unfortunately the error has come again, Just after adding the following library i am getting `ClassDefNotFound` in one of my class.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.+'
}
```

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/video_lib/android/utils/NetworkClient;

If i remove `commonsware` library, It works fine, but the `commonsware` library is essential for some other API, and i have to use it.

The error may be due to `gradle conflict`.  Kindly guide me how to identify and remove gradle-conflict.

Comment: it is conflicting that means the commonsware lib may be including the google play lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `gradle app:dependencies` to view the dependency tree. Look for the multiple versions of the same library and / or multiple versions of libraries from the same family. Then use force to leave only one of them.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't worked on `gradle app:dependencies`. Kindly guide me or share a link from where i can learn how to execute `gradle app:dependencies`, and do i need to write anything on build.grade to forcefully remove libraries.

Comment: @Kirmani88 You can start from [Gradle userguide dependency management section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). Forcing described in [24.8.2. Using dependency resolve rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:forcing_modules). [Excluding transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies) in corresponding section of that guide.

Comment: @Kirmani88 as for executing gradle command, you can use the gradle wrapper script android studio should have created in your project's root as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also answer this one as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346988/how-to-exclude-multiple-file-reference-from-gradle-file

Answer (score -1):

Just in case for Multi-dex issue where the method count exceeds 64k limit
use
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

enable the multidex support in your gradle file
multiDexEnabled true

n your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element.