# How to exclude multiple file reference from Gradle file

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

One of the SDK requires `com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.1` in my project. So i added it. After adding it one of the `SDK` that was working fine before, started crashing. If i remove  `com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.1`, it works fine again.

When i check `dependency-tree` of my older project(The one which does not have `commonsware1.1.1` defined in the gradle file) The`commonsware` library does not appear in dependency-tree, but when i check the [Method Count](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts) It displays `commonsware` methods there in the  `method count` list.

[image]

After adding `commonsware` in the gradle file,

```
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.1'
```

It displays `commonsware` in the `dependency-tree` as well as in `method-count`, but `commonsware` is displaying `63-Methods` in `Method Count`  here.

[image]

This may be the reason that after adding the `commonsware1.1.1`, the app is crashing on the older SDK.

The 2 `commonsware` libraries may be conflicting, Kindly guide me how to tackle this.

Comment: Could you please share the whole dependency tree (preferably as a text output from `dependencies` command? it can be too large to post, so uploading it to e.g. github is ok)

Comment: @Ivan : You can view the dependency from the following link: http://textuploader.com/d5mg6

Comment: you're still seeing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/video_lib/android/utils/NetworkClient;`? Could you please share the whole stacktrace for the error so I can see who was requesting this class