# Error While Trying to Create Signed APK - Magic number did not match

Tags: java, android, apk, signed

I am new in Android Development, and trying to create the Signed APK, it used to work fine previously but from few days its showing the error message whenever I try to generate signed APK, I have been searching many times and checked many question, but cannot find any solution, below is the error message I get when I click, "Generate Signed APK"

```
Magic number did not match
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Magic number did not match
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxSerializerKt.readKdbxHeader(KdbxSerializer.kt:146)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxSerializer.createUnencryptedInputStream(KdbxSerializer.kt:61)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxStreamFormat.load(kdbx.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.loadKdbx(kdbx.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:82)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImplKt.computeProvider(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:228)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.PasswordSafe.getInstance(PasswordSafe.java:28)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep.<init>(KeystoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.<init>(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.GenerateSignedApkAction.actionPerformed(GenerateSignedApkAction.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Did u recently updated sdk or studio?

Comment: Yes. I updated a few days back. I have tried uninstalling and installing again.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: not yet my dear, its still same I have started to use another pc for android.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly KeePass DB was corrupted or something else.
find the file (on Windows it would typically be

**"C:\Users\admin.AndroidStudio3.2\config\c.kdbx"**

(for 2018.1 version on Windows 10);
others -- see Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs )

**delete "c.kdbx" file**

**Make backup of it (just in case)**
**Delete it (while IDE is closed, of course)**

launch IDE and see if it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Not Exactly the solution. But a workaround for those who want to build RELEASE APK**

**Reason for the Error for me** - During building, computer got shutdown unexpectedly.

**If you want to build release APK** - Build it using gradle commandline. It works (for now)

([Build Android Studio app via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line))

Comment: thank you, that was same issue withme, my computer shutdown unexpectedly while working, and its still the same. I started using another computer for android studio but than you for the suggestion regarding command line.Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome indeed. Hope people find this helpful in dire situations.