# Couldn't build Android Studio project via Ubuntu terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle

My question seems to be similar to the question [Build Android Studio app via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line) but it is a bit different. 
I have an android studio project and everything is ok when building using Android studio IDE but I **need** build the project via **ubuntu** terminal.
I type ./gradlew build I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ContentProvider'.
```

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.

And when typing sudo ./gradlew, I get these errors:

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1899)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:91)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
    ... 26 more
```

even the project is built well without any errors via IDE.
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to import eclipse android project?

Comment: no Android Studio Project

Comment: The `trustAnchors` keyword indicates an SSL/TLS problem (misconfiguration of your JRE or JRE too old).

Comment: @Robert Actually I doubt about that but I tried to use oracle 9 and then switched to openjdk-8 but for nothing. May it be because of ubuntu my ubuntu is 17.10?

Comment: Java uses the trusted certificates of the linux system. May be one certificate triggers this error. Also check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47001608/150978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem and the solution was as the following:
1- Installing jdk8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

To be sure about java type:

```
java -version
```

2- Installing Gradle version 4.4.1 (This is gone well with me):

```
wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip
sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.4.1/bin
```

To be sure about gradle type:

```
gradle -v
```

3- Install ca-certificates-java by typing:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates-java
```

4-  restart your pc.

Then type:

```
gradle build
```

In case you encountered en error like:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.

add this to build script of app module.

```
android {
  lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
}
```

and everything should go well.