# How to compile with javac compiler the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: java, android, compilation

How to compile with javac compiler the AndroidManifest.xml file from Android project? Or another console utility. There are such tools?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  You can't compile an XML file with a Java compiler.  An XML file is not Java source code.

Comment: What I think you are **trying** to ask is answered by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line

Answer (score -1):

Just use the android sdk gradle build from the command line