# Did anything happen? [trying to automate android build]

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm an android newbie. [People tell me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629290/1585345) I can use gradlew.bat to build an apk. When I launch it in debug it seems to function, but I can't find the .apk anywhere. What's going on?

```
e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>android\gradlew.bat --status

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set DIRNAME=e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion\android\

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if "e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion\android\" == "" set DIRNAME=.

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set APP_BASE_NAME=gradlew

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set APP_HOME=e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion\android\

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set JAVA_EXE=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java.exe

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if exist "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java.exe" goto init

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if not "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if "@eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NT_args

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set CMD_LINE_ARGS=

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set _SKIP=2

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if "x--status" == "x" goto execute

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set CMD_LINE_ARGS=--status

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>goto execute

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>set CLASSPATH=e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion\android\\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java.exe"    "-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew" -classpath "e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion\android\\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain --status
PID STATUS   INFO
22140 IDLE     4.10.1
27356 IDLE     4.10.1
22428 STOPPED  (after being idle for 6 minutes and not recently used and to reclaim system memory)

Only Daemons for the current Gradle version are displayed. See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if "0" == "0" goto mainEnd

e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" endlocal
e:\dev\mobility\mob-ion>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `gradlew.bat build` command, that should create the .apk on `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`.

Also check `gradlew.bat task` as it will show you more available tasks, like `installDebug` that installs the app in a connected device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know perfectly for this method but, when i built apk using CLI it generates at below path.

> platform/android/build/output/apk/debug/debug.apk

May this method will also generate there.

Comment: That’s for Cordova, not capacitor