# How to Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace

Tags: android, flutter

I keep getting this error and i don't seem to find any help online. I am new to flutter and android studio. any help is well appreciated

- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  > Where:
  >   Build file 'C:\Android\Android Studios\cravings\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not open dsl remapped class cache for eq9b73nqpstq0kplnrtticwqc (C:\Users\October Price.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\flutter_f2f86ofj12jp9hosmvp06kahh\eq9b73nqpstq0kplnrtticwqc\dsl9d9bdfa13168004751655a79e56a065e).
  >   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
- Try:

  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your configuration. Did you install Flutter and follow all the instructions from the website? Can you run `flutter doctor` and add the output to your question?

Comment: well, i did...but again, i can't because as i said, i am new to this. let me run flutter doctor

Comment: here flutter doctor's report https://www.screencast.com/t/pD8sAejEQ

Comment: Have you accepted the Licenses like it's asking you? Next time please share the text, not a screenshot.

Comment: okay! i sure!. yes i accepted the license when installing

Comment: But flutter doctor is saying that you still have licenses to accept. Try running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Comment: i could share my screen through any desk if don't mind

Comment: i really don't know how or where to run the command you suggested i run

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works. We help you solve your problem through StackOverflow, not through external tools.

Comment: Open the command line and run that command. If you are on Windows just press the Start key and write "cmd" and press Enter to open the command line. Then paste the command and press Enter.

Comment: oh okay! so i did that and it says flutter is not recognized as an internal or external command...i must say, i installed flutter from android studio plugin marketplace

Comment: how can i accept the license then?

Comment: You need to replace the `flutter` command with the full location of the flutter binary where you installed the SDK. As you seem to not have the flutter command available in your env.

Comment: okay! can you guide me to do that?

Comment: That comment was already the instruction. But this is already getting off topic from your original question.

Comment: i don't know how to replace the command.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try running the `assembleDebug` Gradle task manually.

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

But there could be something wrong with your configuration.
Run `flutter doctor -v` and see if everything is setup correctly.

Otherwise you can try deleting the Gradle cache folder which seem to bet at `C:\Users\October Price.gradle\caches`.

Comment: it appears flutter is not recognized in my windows since i installed it from an android studio. and i haven't accepted a license but i have no idea how to rectify that

Comment: i did delete the Gradle cache as you suggested but it didn't change anything

Comment: Then try to follow the Windows installation guide, especially the part with the 'Update your path' part: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows - I am not sure Android Studio actually installs flutter.

Comment: okay, so i deleted android studio from my computer and did a new installation with flutter as well and have it checked but i am still getting an error

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\October Price\Desktop\cravings\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> C:\Users\October Price\Desktop\cravings\android\key.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Some `key.properties` file is missing, you should first try to run a simple example app. It seems you are trying to run an existing project without everything being setup correctly.

Comment: okay so following your advice, i run a simple app which run smoothly but when i copy the files from my old one to the new one, i get same error....

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\October Price\Desktop\cravings\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> C:\Users\October Price\Desktop\cravings\android\key.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: now, there's a key.property file in the old one which i didn't copy. do i have to copy that too?

Comment: Probably, since it says that it is missing. This is nothing related to a normal flutter app though.

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: C:\Users\October Price\Desktop\cravings\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\octoberprice\cravings\MainActivity.kt: (10, 48): Type mismatch: inferred type is FlutterEngine but PluginRegistry! was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

Comment: finally got it to run to run. thanks guys. your help was much appreciated. i must say login doesn't work and i am again stacked lol

Comment: It may be build for an older flutter version, but that's just guessing.

Answer (score 14):

You can set your android compiler to always run with `--stacktrace` modifier.

- Head to **Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler**
- Add `--debug` or `--info` or `--stacktrace` (Or combination of them) to the **Command line options**

[image]

In your case clearing `C:\Users\October Price\.gradle\caches` folder and re-syncing the project might help.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `--verbose` to get the full flutter stack trace. so for example:

`flutter build apk --debug --verbose`

Comment: I am wondering why so many upvotes, the command just shows a more detailed error, we do not get info about how to fix the problem.

Comment: The detailed error helps guide you to not just finding where the exact issue is occuring from, but also to know where to start from, for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gradlew` command to run from command line. to get more details of `gradlew` you can type `gradlew --help`. For further information regarding How to run from Command line follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line).

Comment: I don't remember how I solved this but I think this should be closed now. Thanks everyone for reaching out

Answer (score -1):

delete build.gradle it will work

Comment: it'd be nice if you explained why this works (what exactly is the problem that it solves), what exactly it does (how it solves that underlying problem), and what happens after deleting the file. Ex. does it get regenerated?