# Android: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.drodriguez.my_rents;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
//        FlutterYodo1Mas.getInstance().build(flutterEngine, this);
    }
}
```

With that line commented it compiles ok but otherwise I get this with no more information:

```
MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        FlutterYodo1Mas.getInstance().build(flutterEngine, this);
        ^
  symbol:   variable FlutterYodo1Mas
  location: class MainActivity
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

More info: paste.ofcode.org/3bYrZ9afhH7YZWBkGwcTJWk

I tried removing /android/.gradle folder.

FlutterYodo1Mas.java is placed next to the MainActivity. I use Flutter but I don't think it's related to this error since these 2 files are .java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated]

<s>You need to import the package of FlutterYodo1Mas class in MainActivity.java.</s>

import com.example.FlutterYodo1Mas;

On the second file, FlutterYodo1Mas.java, the first line wasn't your project name so you had to specify package com.drodriguez.my_rents;

Comment: MainActivity file was fine, the other file was missing the first line the MainActivity has with project name

Comment: Opps sorry, I have updated with my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to understand your issue without the complete stacktrace/error logs. I would suggest the efficient and simplest way, you can try delete the android folder, and run  `flutter create -a java .` inside your app folder, to regenerate android folder, then merge your codes & configurations. There's no harm of trying, make sure you backup your existing code :)

Comment: if I do that I create an android folder without Kotlin support and that's a problem for some packages. I opened this a few days ago: https://github.com/ja2375/add_2_calendar/issues/80#event-5241646099

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186072/how-to-run-with-stacktrace-option-to-get-the-stack-trace

You can try running the compileDebugJavaWithJavac Gradle task manually.

cd android
./gradlew compileDebugJavaWithJavac --stacktrace

Comment: basically the error is the same, but not sure if this extra info helps: paste.ofcode.org/3bYrZ9afhH7YZWBkGwcTJWk

Comment: You need to import your class in your MainActivity.java. 

import com.xxx.FlutterYodo1Mas;

Comment: what stands xxx for? Sorry for the silly question but I tried different combinations

Comment: xxx is the package of FlutterYodo1Mas class. Example: com.example.FlutterYodo1Mas

Comment: aaaah that was the issue. On the second file, FlutterYodo1Mas.java, the first line wasn't my project name so I had to specify package com.drodriguez.my_rents;.

Comment: Create another answer with above info and I'll accept it ;)