# I've tried run the --stacktrace in cmd, but it still fail

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, iot, genymotion

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charts_flutter-0.11.0/lib/src/behaviors/legend/legend_entry_layout.dart:134:45: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
  color ??= Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1!.color;
  ^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s

Comment: you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/60186072/10157127

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:

It was happening with in flutter 2.10.1 Maybe because I had the flutter 2.10.0 already running and later I have upgraded it to 2.10.1 or maybe the other issue.

**Fix** :

So I have deleted flutter from c:\flutter and again extracting the downloaded flutter 2.10.0.completly fixed it.