# how to make an android APK from android files without using AndroidStudio?

Tags: android

I have those three files:

```
  activity_main.xml
  MainActivity.java
  AndroidManifest.xml
```

Those belong to a webview app I found on google...

I want to convert those files into an android apk....

I have no ides at all, just my basic laptop (doesnt support android studio) with internet conection. How can I make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install Google's Android Studio. Go to

https://developer.android.com/studio

and then follow the installation instructions. Do not be surprised if this takes some time! Android Studio is BIG when you have installed the necessary SDKs and perhaps an emulator. Android Studio includes a lot of useful help.

Comment: What operating system does your laptop use? According to the Google Android Studio download page, Android Studio is available for Windows (64 bit), Mac, Linux (64 bit) and Chrome. If, of course, you are using an older version of Windows, with just a 32-bit operating system, then you will have problems! You could try downloading an older version of AS, which is perhaps 32-bit compatible from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: Further to my last comment, you could try Android Studio 3.6.3, There is a 32-bit version available as a .zip file. See android-studio-ide-192.6392135-windows32.zip. Good luck!

Comment: could you please check my next question related to this issue, please? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110310/where-to-locate-android-emulator-zip-downloaded-by-browser`  Your answer worked, I just need some small steps to make Android studio works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From command line is posible with

```
 gradlew assembleDebug
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Comment: In this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line

Comment: in this link : https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676

is good for you