# where to locate android emulator.zip downloaded by browser?

Tags: android, installation, android-emulator

Im having problems downloading Android Studio for 32 bit (AS version 3.6.3). It stopped in:

```
  Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 28.0.25)".
  Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5395263.zip
  JavaexceptionSomething....
```

Then I decided to paste that url in chrome browser and it downloaded it. I have it now in `download files` in my laptop. I downloaded the next `.zip`

```
   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5395263.zip
```

I want to know...where Im supposed to paste that `.zip` file in order to make work Android Studio? Otherwise it appears an alert

```
Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted.
```

then when trying to follow some tutorials,

```
  Open SDK Manager > Android SDK > Edit > Next > Next... it doesnt download this same zip file. It keep me awaiting indefinitely...
```

**Where should I paste this file in order to make Android Studio work?**

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have now successfully installed Android Studio 3.6.3 32-bit in a 32-bit Windows 10 virtual machine. Apart from needing to increase the disk-size that I had initially allocated, I had no installation problems other than that the Intel HAXM component refused to install (probably because it does not like a 32-bit system). The emulator also installed successfully, so I could not reproduce your problem. I can only think that you do not have enough disk space. In my experience, Android Studio with a couple of emulators needs several 10's GB of free space.

I suggest that you check how much free space you have and then try removing and reinstalling Android Studio.

When it comes to which emulator to use, you should use an ARM emulator and not an -86 emulator (they do not seem to work in a 32-bit environment).

I do not know how old your computer is, but you should seriously consider upgrading to a 64-bit operating system. Everything is now targeted to 64-bit architectures.

Comment: this is not correct answer.