# Build android apps on mobile device without IDE

Tags: android, kotlin, ide

I have a good android mobile device and I'm looking for a way to build android apps using Kotlin. And I don't want to use an IDE. Is there a way to install/download all necessary tools/resources/whatever to my device to make it possible? Thanks

Comment: I saw some people use AIDE (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the command line for do so.

Gradle contains the tasks for creating a proyect, compile, debugging, generating APK/App Bundle, Run in emmulator, etc... but, in Android Studio this was simplified in some way for productivity reasons (imho).

But, If you still want to use the command line with gradle, you can set gradle home /bin folder in the PATH env variables for the OS you use, and then you can apply for work with that.

BTW, Strongly recommend to check this link from [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline).

**UPDATE:**

 
This question is related to this another one, check the answer there.

Link related one: [Build Android Studio app via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line)

Goood luck.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio does a lot of jobs for you so that you can focus on development only. It's not a great idea to ditch IDE completely. You might lose time and money doing that.

But here are some great articles if you're really interested:

[Create a Basic Android App without an IDE](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/10/basic-android-without-an-ide)

[How to make Android apps without IDE from command line](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676)

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I don't mind loosing time as soon as I can understand what's going on :)