# I need to know how to compile these files and folders into an apk file

Tags: android

I am recently employed into this new company as a junior IT support.  I mainly do hardware with very-to-little programming knowledge.

Recently my company upgraded to a newer server and we have changed the location of the databases. However our apps are still pointing towards the old server url/location.  I have been in contact with the app developers on how to change the configuration of the apk; in which it needs to be decompiled.  They are engaged in a big project and was unable to assist me at this moment. Instead, they have given me the whole folder containing all the source code (Shown in the screenshot).

I was asked to:-

1. Change the URL setting in on of the config.ts file contained in the res folder
2. Recompile everything to APK so that the 'new' APK can be installed on our mobile Android devices.

I have attempted to use the Android Studio program to open this folder and made the necessary url changes.

However I am stuck on how to get the program to 'build' the APK for me.  Did I miss something? [Screenshots on file explorer & Android Studio (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUGCr.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrYu3.png)

I tried to import the sc files and folders into Android Studio and still can't see the drop down menu build APK.

Answer (score 0):

In the top bar of Android Studio, you'll click:

Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK.

[image: GenerateDialog]

- Select the "APK" option. Click next.
- You'll need to enter the keystore path, and password, which means asking the developers. Click next.
- You can then either select "debug" or "release".
- Since you want to deploy to users, select release. Click Create. Android Studio will compile the project, and export the file.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering.  However I have clicked on the top bar 'Build' menu, however the options I have are only "Make Module xxx", "Analyze APK", "Deploy Module to App Engine" as shown in one of the screenshots earlier.

Comment: @AbamCoilJB That's a first. It probably has to do with your project structure. Have you tried building the module?

Comment: I wished I knew.  As I have clarified earlier, I am just a junior level IT staff.  Very basic programming knowledge..  You can refer to my earlier screenshot to see the contents of the folder and files provided by the developer.

Comment: @AbamCoilJB Sorry about that. Maybe try this: `gradle assemble` command in the `src` directory via the Command Line. The resulting .apks are in app/[appname]/build/outputs/apk/[debug/release]. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line)