# Use CMake to build simple Android app - No C++

Tags: android, cmake, command-line

I've searched for days trying to understand what is going on.

I fail to understand why building a simple Android app - no C++ code - with CMake from the command-line isn't standard practice.  Ignoring the results which include solutions for C++ and the NDK, there is only one solution provided, use the Android Studio.

Well, Android Studio kinda sucks, and certainly can't be launched from within Jenkins for a CI build.

What's the solution to this ?

Where is there any good documentation for how to build an Android app from the command-line ?

Comment: Just making sure you understand that Android apps uses [Gradle as its build system](https://developer.android.com/build), see: [Build Android Studio app via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398041/295004)